# Make a JPanel not draw its background (Transparent)

Tags: java, user-interface

Is it possible, in Java, to make a `JPanel` skip drawing its background thus being transparent except for the components on it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`setOpaque(false)`

It'll pass off painting the background to its parent, which may draw its own background.

You can do a screen capture and then use that to paint the background of the panel.

Answer (score 5):

This article seems to have some handy info on how to create shaped and transparent windows in Java:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

Comment: Java SE 7 is required. I used Linux which has OpenJDK 6.0 and does not worked.

Answer (score 2):

Technically a JPanel may start off non-opague. This was true for the Gtk look & feel in 1.5 (or 1.4?), but no other PL&Fs as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using NetBeans, Then Do these steps:-

1. Right Click on `JPanel`.
2. Scroll Down and Search For (( Opaque )). It must be there.
3. Uncheck it.
4. Now your `JPanel` background will be removed and what will appear in
   `JPanel` Background is your Background of `JFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class TransparentJPanel extends JPanel
{
    TransparentJPanel()
    {
        super() ;
        this.setOpaque( false ) ; // this will make the JPanel transparent 
                                  // but not its components (JLabel, TextField etc.)
        this.setLayout( null ) ;
    }
}
```