# Vista glass border effect in Java Swing/AWT

Tags: java, swing, drawing, blur

I'm trying to create an overlay with a Vista Aero Glass -like background in place of a normal window. Part of my answer seems to be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926/java-make-a-jpanel-not-draw-its-background), but I'm wondering how to get a blur effect in Swing/AWT. [This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/ImageFilter.htm) looks like a start:

```
public BufferedImage processImage(BufferedImage image) {
    float[] blurMatrix = { 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f /  
            9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f / 9.0f };
    BufferedImageOp blurFilter = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3, 3, blurMatrix),
            ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null);
    return blurFilter.filter(image, null);
}
```

...but I'd really like to get a close match. It seems the process should be:

1. Blur the background image
2. Paint over with a transparent grey (or whatever bg color you're going for)
3. Then paint opaque window contents

If I get this right, I might throw in the Aero window border shadows.

Am I on the right track? How precisely should I do the blur to get the same look? Maybe someone has solved this problem already? (For reference, open the Vista start menu and look at the right side.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution to hand but you can definitely overlay a color in the blurring stage. Everything you'll ever need to know about Swing effects and Swing image effects is in the excellent [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/). The answer to your question is definitely in there.

In fact, if you look in the examples section and download the chapter 8 code from that site, there is code to do the blur and tint that you require.

Thanks,
jT