# making transperent background

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make a JPanel not draw its background (Transparent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926/make-a-jpanel-not-draw-its-background-transparent)

i want to make my application background as transperent.how to do this?

Comment: No downvote. You can google this http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&biw=1024&bih=676&q=Transparent+window+in+Java&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&bav=on.2,or.&fp=85e281e4e6cce0be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search could find you the answer but look at this topic:

[Make a JPanel not draw its background (Transparent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926/make-a-jpanel-not-draw-its-background-transparent)

Comment: No downvote. It should be posted as a comment, not as an answer.