# How do i make a JPanel Transparent?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, transparency, jpanel

I tried using 
    setOpaque(false);
 but it just makes the background of the JPanel white.. How do i make it not draw the panel at all?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926/make-a-jpanel-not-draw-its-background-transparent nice solution.

Comment: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/swinghks_hack41/index.html that's a more in depth version of the solution the previous link suggested, just take a screenshot of the background and load that in after you have set the jpanel setOpaque(false);

let me know if this is not what you mean.

Comment: well yes and no, isnt there a simpler way to just make a JPanel transparent? because this is over complicating it for what it is used for...

Comment: No that I know of, if you can describe the situation I might have a better idea.

Comment: Can you describe in mor detail what you want to achieve from a user point of view. What kind of functionality do you want to offer. Perhaps you can solve your issue using a `JLayeredPane` or a `JLayer`, but it is not clear from the question

Comment: i want to make UI for my game. The only way i know of doing it is using JPanels and just having mouselisteners on them... so i want to make one of the jpanels transparent so i cant position my actual jpanel in the right spot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered the question yourself.

The JPanel didn't become white, but it showed -- because it became non-opaque -- the JFrame (or other controls) behind it.

Comment: Then how do i make it not show but the components inside of it show

Comment: @user1167681 Define "not show" (it is technically "not shown" now). Do you want the "desktop background to be visible"? If so, see the question linked by Mr D.

Comment: Yes i want the background of the panel behind it to show up basically its fully transparent but its still there..