# Setting background image

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, background-image

How can I get rid of that gray box?

This is what I'm talking about:

[image]

i would really appreciate if you could help me out

Full code here: http://pastebin.com/nrpCTjvV

```
public final void initUI() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(90, 155, 40, 60)));

    JButton NewGame = new JButton  ("New Game!");
    JButton Highscore = new JButton("Highscore");
    JButton Credits = new JButton  ("Credits");
    JButton Website = new JButton  ("Website");
    JButton Exit = new JButton     ("Exit");

    panel.add(NewGame);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
    panel.add(Highscore);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
    panel.add(Credits);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
    panel.add(Website);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
    panel.add(Exit);

    final ButtonGroup entreeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton radioButton;
    panel.add(radioButton = new JRadioButton("Music1"));
    radioButton.setActionCommand("Music1");
    entreeGroup.add(radioButton);
    panel.add(radioButton = new JRadioButton("Music2"));
    radioButton.setActionCommand("Music2");
    entreeGroup.add(radioButton);
    panel.add(radioButton = new JRadioButton("No Music", true));
    radioButton.setActionCommand("No Music");
    entreeGroup.add(radioButton);

    add(panel);
    pack();

    setTitle("Title");
    JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("background.png"));
add(background);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(400, 400);

}
```

Comment: panel.setOpaque(false); possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926/make-a-jpanel-not-draw-its-background-transparent

Comment: @user2287319, No, that is not the proper solution just to make the panel non-opaque. Swing was NOT designed to display two components in one location on the BorderLayout. Your solution happens to work because of a hack. This is not a good way to learn to program. For example, a pack() should not be done on the frame until all components are added. Remove that line of code and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

```
add(panel);
pack();
setTitle("Title");
JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("background.png"));
add(background);
```

The default layout manager for a JFrame is a BorderLayout. When you add a component without specifying a constraint the component is added to the CENTER. You can't add multiple components to a single location.

Instead you need to use a different component as the background. Then you add your panel to this component. Check out [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/). Then code would be something like:

```
Background background = new BackgroundPanel(...);
background.add(panel);
add(background);
setResizable(false);
pack();
...
```